# Create anchor from Wysiwyg editor

Tags: links, wysiwyg

Is there any way to create internal anchors without using the HTML rendering option?
I don't mind but I guess my customer will ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "tinyMCE Advanced" plugin has a special icon for that.
The default WordPress installation don't offer the anchor icon/attribute editor.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of [mike23's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19521/create-anchor-from-wysiwyg-editor/19527#19527). Here you can just append the anchor button to the wysiwyg panel.

```
function set_tinymce_buttons( $initArray ) {
    $initArray['theme_advanced_buttons1'] .= ',anchor';
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'set_tinymce_buttons');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple non-plugin solution, you can paste this into your `functions.php` :

```
function set_tinymce_buttons( $initArray ) {
    $initArray['theme_advanced_buttons1'] ='formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,charmap,|,pastetext,pasteword,|,removeformat,|,anchor,link,unlink,|,undo,redo';
    $initArray['theme_advanced_buttons2'] = '';
    $initArray['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'h2,h3,h4,p';
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'set_tinymce_buttons');
```

With that you can set the two lines of buttons as well as the tags in the *Format* dropdown.

See [this page](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Buttons/controls) for options.

Answer (score -1):

you can easily create bookmarking tag just follow these steps :

1. Set your Destination

   ```
   <h2 id="anchor"> Destination of your Anchor </h2>
   ```
2. Make target Hyperlink

   ```
   <a href="#anchor">Click Me for check our Anchor</a>
   ```

[image]

please see above image for better explanation

Comment: Don't use answers to spam. Your link is totally not relevant. Do not roll back my changes, I will flag this as spam.